# GDAL compilation to .NET (C#) use

Tags: gdal, c#, .net

I want compile `GDAL` library for use in C# program. I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. First, I compiled `GDAL` C++. As a result I have DLLs and libraries (No problems) . Next, I tried to compile with [instruction](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrCsharpCompile), because I want use `GDAL` in C# program. But, I don't understand what should I do in this step.

> **Creating the SWIG interface code**
>   For creating the interface execute the following command.
>
> `nmake /f makefile.vc interface`
>
> Previous Step make's error when regenerates the *PINVOKE.cs files ,so
>   skip to next step ,it will work

I tried to skip this step, but always had the same exception (shown below). As result I don't have DLLs to use in C#...

```
    ogr\OsrPINVOKE.cs(192,10): error CS0111: Type 'OSGeo.OGR.OsrPINVOKE' already
        defines a member called 'OsrPINVOKE' with the same parameter types
ogr\OsrPINVOKE.cs(188,10): (Location of symbol related to previous error)
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\csc.EXE"' :
 return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

What should I do to compile `GDAL` to C#?

Comment: Why not just use the pre-built binaries from here: http://www.gisinternals.com/. I have used them for VS 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015. Comes with the SWIG wrappers and binaries. No fuss, no muss.

Comment: Ok, I try and uses binaries.